# How to work with ACL in .NET Core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, acl

ASP.NET Core MVC 2

My web-application will be hosted on IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012 R2). I need to work with ACL of some files and directories. I attached [System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl/) package to my project, but I have some problems still... Also I see some info about this theme on Microsoft site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2). But I don't see the code examples.

I know how to work with ACL through .NET Framework but I don't know how to do it in .NET Core 2. This is my code with my questions (I commented code which works in .NET Framework but doesn't work in .NET Core 2):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

// NuGet package: System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace ACL_Sandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var fileName = "data.txt";
                File.Create(fileName);

                // How to get the FileSecurity of the file in .NET Core 2?
                FileSecurity sec = null; // File.GetAccessControl(true,true,typeof(NTAccount));

                AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = sec.GetAccessRules(true, true, null);

                foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("AccessControlType: {0}", rule.AccessControlType);
                    Console.WriteLine("FileSystemRights: {0}", rule.FileSystemRights);
                    Console.WriteLine("IdentityReference.Value: {0}", rule.IdentityReference.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n=======\n");
                }

                var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null);
                string usersAccount = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
                FileSystemAccessRule newRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(usersAccount, 
                    FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile, AccessControlType.Allow);
                sec.AddAccessRule(newRule);

                // How to set the access rule for the file in .NET Core 2?
                // File.SetAccessRule(sec);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key for exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

JetBrains Rider IDE for the class `FileSecurity` shows me such code sources:

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity
// Assembly: System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// MVID: 95551778-530B-4B9F-8EB6-1D54F85B3C4B
// Assembly location: /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.5/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll

namespace System.Security.AccessControl
{
  [SecurityCritical]
  public sealed class FileSecurity : FileSystemSecurity
  {
    public FileSecurity()
    {
      throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(SR.PlatformNotSupported_AccessControl);
    }

    public FileSecurity(string fileName, AccessControlSections includeSections)
    {
      throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(SR.PlatformNotSupported_AccessControl);
    }
  }
}
```

This is not encouraging ...

Is it possible to work with ACL in .NET Core 2? 
If "yes" then how can I get the the FileSecurity of the file in .NET Core 2? 
Also, if "yes" then how can I set the access rule for the file in .NET Core 2?

Comment: Use SetAccessControl method of FileInfo class, but remember that you need sufficient privileges.

Comment: Did you figure it out??

Comment: @ScriptKitty, .Net Core2 hasn't `FileInfo.SetAccessControl()` method.

Comment: There actually appears a `SetAccessControl()` instance method for FileInfo when I add the `System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl` package from NuGet and then add `using System.Security.AccessControl;`. This using .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? If the class exists in .NET Core, should it run in all platforms?

Comment: @JoãoPereira no, I not found solution.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this with .NET Core 2.2, but with .NET Core 3.0 I have used the following successfully. You must declare `using System.Security.AccessControl;` and reference the [System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl/) NuGet package as noted by Jonas in the comments above. The nice thing is that this code is then compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 2.0-4.x if you are multi-targeting.

```
// Setup which parts of the ACL will be modified
AccessControlSections includeSections = AccessControlSections.Access | AccessControlSections.Group | AccessControlSections.Owner;

// FileSecurity sec = File.GetAccessControl(fileName, includeSections);
FileSecurity sec = new FileSecurity(fileName, includeSections);

// ==> Change file security (sec) here

// File.SetAccessControl(fileName, sec);
new FileInfo(fileName).SetAccessControl(sec);
```